# How to calculate this Z= 4 || j2

Tags: impedance

is i(t)=5 cos(10t+40°) A.
A resistor 4 ohm is parallel with an inductor 0.2H.

ZL=j2

Z= 4 || j2

How do i calculate this?

Comment: The same way you calculate resistances, but with impedances.

Comment: See here http://www.electrical4u.com/rl-parallel-circuit/

Comment: @Oka is there a way using calculator?

Comment: No need using a calculator. Use "Impedance of Parallel RL Circuit" equation (in the previous link), with R=4 and XL=2.

Comment: 1.78885438 ohms and you do need a calculator.

Comment: heheee if the answer just Z= (16/20) + j (32/20), no need a calculator, but if we must know the value of its magnitude and phase angle... sure we need a calculator

Comment: @Oka - So you guys forgot how to divide arbitrary numbers using paper & pencil? Shame!

Comment: okay... @Ricardo then I forgot how to do square root and arctan using paper & pencil :D

Comment: @Oka - Ok, you got me. But there's gotta be tables (on old books) with all that printed on, I suppose.

Comment: @Ricardo yes., so we need google square root and arctan table,  print them, and paste them on the wall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallel impedances are found using the product-over-sum method i.e. multiply resistance by reactance and then divide by the sum of resistance and reactance: -

Therefore Z = \$\dfrac{j\omega L\times R}{j\omega L+ R}\$

But you need to take a few more steps to get a numerical answer. The above becomes: -

\$\dfrac{j\omega LR}{j\omega L+ R}\times \dfrac{R-j\omega L}{R-j\omega L}=\$

\$\dfrac{(j\omega LR)(R-j\omega L)}{R^2 + \omega^2L^2}\$ = \$\dfrac{j\omega LR^2+\omega^2 L^2R}{R^2 + \omega^2L^2}\$

At this point note that there is no j term in the denominator and given your numbers the denominator is \$4^2 + 2^2\$ = 20.

To calculate the numerator plug in the numbers to get \$(2^2\cdot 4) +j(2\cdot4^2)\$ = 16+j32.

Then square each term of the numerator and take the square root of the sum leaving the magnitude of the numerator as 35.777.

Finally divide by the denominator and the impedance magnitude is 1.7888 ohms.

Or if you want to bypass all that maths do this: -

|Impedance| = \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{R^2}+\dfrac{1}{\omega^2 L^2}}}\$

There is [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/imped.html) calculator: -

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that the product over sum method here only applies to two parallel impedances. If you have more than two parallel impedances, you then need to use the reciprocal approach

Comment: @efox29 good point and luckily I covered both

Comment: @efox29 for parallel impedances A, B and C the reciprocal formula also resolves to a type of product over sum - \$\dfrac{ABC}{AB+AC+AB}\$ - I had to think about this and I can see a trend!

Comment: A, B, C and D in parallel is \$\dfrac{ABCD}{BCD+ACD+ABD+ABC}\$

Comment: Ah so it does. I stared at your ABC example, and it didnt make sense because the A's would cancel out. But it was a typo. One of the AB's should be BC. But this is good to know!

Comment: @efox29 oops, it should be \$\dfrac{ABC}{AB+AC+BC}\$!

Answer (score 0):

\$Z = \dfrac{1}{\sum\dfrac{1}{x \; or \; r}}\$ for impedances in parallel.

You should find out how to divide 1 by complex numbers using Google easily enough. :-)